# Contact from not working after update to jquery 1.9

Tags: javascript, php, contact-form

I have this contact form for 3-4 years and it was working fine until jquery 1.9

html

```
<form id="Newsletter">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td><input id="jezik" name="jezik" type="hidden" value="hr" />
                <input id="NewsletterIme" name="NewsletterIme" type="text" onFocus="if(this.value == 'Ime i prezime*') { this.value = ''; }" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Ime i prezime*';}"  value="Ime i prezime*" /><br>
               <input id="NewsletterEmail" name="NewsletterEmail" type="text" onFocus="if(this.value == 'E-mail*') { this.value = ''; }" onBlur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'E-mail*';}"  value="E-mail*" /></td>
                <td style=" vertical-align:bottom;"><input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        <div id="note1" style="clear:both;"></div>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Newsletter").submit(function(){
    var str = $(this).serialize();
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/newsletter-obrada.php",
       data: str,
       success: function(msg){
                    $("#note1").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
                        var jezik = $('#jezik').val();
                        if(msg != 'OK') 
                            {
                            result = msg;
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            window.location.replace("/" + jezik + "/thank-you");
                            }
                        $(this).html(result);
                    });
                }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

php

```
<?php
/*
Credits: Bit Repository
URL: http://www.bitrepository.com/
*/
    require_once('admin/config.php');

define("WEBMASTER_EMAIL", 'luka@fer-projekt.com');

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
$jezik = $_POST['jezik'];
$NewsletterEmail = trim($_POST['NewsletterEmail']);
$NewsletterIme = $_POST['NewsletterIme'];
$NewsletterGodiste = $_POST['NewsletterGodiste'];
$NewsletterVrsta = $_POST['NewsletterVrsta'];
$sigureca = $_POST['sigureca'];
$poruka = stripslashes($_POST['poruka']);
$error = '';

//jezici
if($jezik == "hr") {
$tekst_kontakt_greska1 = "Niste upisali ime. <br>";
$tekst_kontakt_greska2 = "Niste odabrali grupu. <br>";
$tekst_kontakt_greska3 = "Niste upisali e-mail. <br>";
$tekst_kontakt_greska4 = "Neispravan e-mail. <br>";
$tekst_kontakt_greska5 = "Neispravan sigurnosni kod. <br><br>";
}
if($jezik == "en") {
$tekst_kontakt_greska1 = "You didn’t write your name. <br>";
$tekst_kontakt_greska2 = "You didn’t write your group. <br>";
$tekst_kontakt_greska3 = "You didn’t write your e-mail. <br>";
$tekst_kontakt_greska4 = "Invalid e-mail. <br>";
$tekst_kontakt_greska5 = "Invalid security code. <br><br>";
}


//provjera imena
if(strpos($NewsletterIme, '*'))
{
$error .= $tekst_kontakt_greska1;
}
//checks for an email
if (empty($NewsletterEmail)) {
    $error .= $tekst_kontakt_greska3;
    } else {
        if (!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", stripslashes($NewsletterEmail))) {
        $error .= $tekst_kontakt_greska4;
    } // if eregi
} // if empty email
//provjera imena

if(!$error)
{


$mail = mysql_query("INSERT INTO newsletter (NewsletterEmail, NewsletterIme) VALUES ('$NewsletterEmail', '$NewsletterIme')");


if($mail)
{
echo 'OK';
}

}
else
{
echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
}

}
?>
```

So now noting happens when I click on submit bottun. If I change to jquery 1.8 it works fine. Anybody have any idea?

Comment: Do you see any error messages? Does it make the call to your php? Where does it stop? What doesn't happen in the code that should?

Comment: It wa no error, just no working. Now it's fixed, thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX events should be attached to document as per jquery 1.9 change log.

```
   $("#note1").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
```

Change it to this:

```
 $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
```

Documentation

1. http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/
2. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.9 the global Ajax events are only triggered on the document node: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#ajax-events-should-be-attached-to-document